# auditing opened/closed ports on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, port

Is there an auditing tool to check which and when ports are opened and closed on Linux?
My goal is to run my application and check its ports usage.
lsof or netstat don't fit because they just tell me which ports are currently opened, and looping on such command won't give me accurate results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strace -f -e trace=bind mvn install
```

strace will displays the bind sytem call each time my application an the children processes open a port.